# How to connect codeigniter controller method from Jquery code in a view file (placed in folder)

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete, codeigniter-2

I am using the autocomplete plugin in Jquery as follows:

```
$(function(){
    $("#username").autocomplete({
        source: "http://localhost/websitename/index.php/admin/suggest_names"  // path to the method in controller
        }); 
    });
```

The code for the text box is

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username">
```

The suggest_names method in controller in turn calls a method in the model

I have tried providing the path to the method in controller by using

```
source: "admin/suggest_names"
```

in the above code.

However this is not working when the file is placed in a sub folder within the views folder `application/views/admin`. This works when the file is placed directly within the views folder.

I have tried using site_url but this does not work as well. (the form helper function is loaded in the administrator)

Can you suggest where I am making a mistake and suggest the syntax for the code to be used.

Comment: can you explain what error it shows in console when it not work.

Answer (score 0):

Stick to the following structure:

VIEW:

Your jquery function must be in a view file (it can be in the

> Application/Views

directory or in a subdirectory of view). A view file is displayed in the browser and so the jquery code can run on client side. The controller is called from here. Your first code block example seems to be correct. You can also use: `source: "/index.php/admin/suggest_names"`.

CONTROLLER:

A Controller (in your case called `admin`) is simply a class file that is named in a way that can be associated with a URI. They are placed in the

> Application/Controllers

directory or a subdirectory of it. In your case you are calling the function `suggest_names()`, where you prepare the $data you want to output in the view file and call the database functions from a model (that last one is optional, you could treat the database functions from the controller as well).

MODELS:

Models are PHP classes that are designed to work with information in your database. They are placed in the

> Application/Models

directory or subdirectory of it.